# deserializing xml to object - xmlns='' was not expected

Tags: c#, xml

I'am getting an error while deserializing xml.
Error:There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
inner Exception: Profile xmlns='' was not expected.
here is my profile class, xml and read function:

```
     public class Profile
     {
        private string _profilename;
        private string _iprotocol;
        private string _macaddress;
        private string _prostatus;
        public string ProfileName
        {
            get { return _profilename; }
            set { _profilename = value; }
        }
        public string IProtocol
        {
            get { return _iprotocol; }
            set { _iprotocol = value; }
        }
        public string MacAddress
        {
            get { return _macaddress; }
            set { _macaddress = value; }
        }
        public string ProStatus
        {
            get { return _prostatus; }
            set { _prostatus = value; }
        }
    }
```

my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Profile>
      <ProfileName>Test</ProfileName>
      <IProtocol>192.168.1.1</IProtocol>
      <MacAddress>60-e3-27-37-cf-60</MacAddress>
      <ProStatus>Happy</ProStatus>
    </Profile><?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Profile>
      <ProfileName>Test</ProfileName>
      <IProtocol>192.168.1.1</IProtocol>
      <MacAddress>60-e3-27-37-cf-60</MacAddress>
      <ProStatus>Happy</ProStatus>
    </Profile>
```

read function

```
    private void XmlReader()
    {
       Profile[] Pro;
       XmlSerializer Reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Profile[]));
       TextReader txtReader = new 
                           StreamReader(@"F://SerializationOverview.xml");
      Pro = (Profile[])Reader.Deserialize(txtReader);
    }
```

Comment: Posting the exact input and error helps.

Comment: I see a `Profile` but not a `Profile[]` in your xml. But that  does not explain the  `xmlns`.

Comment: xml may contain more than one profile

Comment: Please post the code of `Profile` class

Comment: @Ranjith - not without an envelope tag. The root has to be a singleton.

Comment: Why does `<?xml version="1.0"?>` appear twice in your XML like format?

Comment: Post and format the error exactly. Right now it looks like __`{` was not expected__. That would mean you're not reading the file you think you are.

Comment: @rene - i'am using FileStream to write xml, and use file mode as append to write second object

Comment: Well, that is your problem. Don't do that.

Comment: @rene - can you suggest a method please?

Comment: First when you write add a new line after each fragment so the <?xml starts on a new line.  Second you need to set your reader method to : XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create("filename", settings);

Comment: Why can't you serialize an in instance `Profile[]`?